# Autofac registration for many interface implementations

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I have several implementations of an interface that I need to register in Autofac, however I'm having trouble figuring out a way to do them all together rather than individually as I have them at the moment:

```
builder.RegisterType<UserDefinedRepository<CType>>().As<IUserDefinedRepository<CType>>();
builder.RegisterType<UserDefinedRepository<LType>>().As<IUserDefinedRepository<LType>>();
```

Both `CType` and `LType` have the same base type and the Type parameter of the Interface and class implementation have the restriction of the same type.

I've read plenty of examples with Autofac implementation, but most seem too complex for what I'm trying to do and the documentation isn't very helpful (from my understanding of it anyway!).

I already have registrations of all my other repositories which has been working well for years, but they all have concrete implementations of the interfaces:

```
var baseRepoType = typeof(InfraAbsRepos.IRepository);
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Infrastructure.Repositories"))
    .Where(t => baseRepoType.IsAssignableFrom(t))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `AsClosedTypesOf` as [noted in the documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html).

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Infrastructure.Repositories"))
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IUserDefinedRepository<>))
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Depending on what you are looking to do, you may need to add in a `Where` clause to filter the list of assembly types; and/or you may want to add an `AsImplementedInterfaces` if there are more interfaces or types you need registered.

If there isn't enough flexibility in `RegisterAssemblyTypes` you can always iterate through the loaded set of types yourself using reflection and maybe combine that with some of the [open generic registration support in Autofac](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components).